# Я в полроста / вполроста встал

Tags: орфография

На одном сайте утверждают, что *в полроста* надо писать, так как правила какие-то теперь другие. Как так? В самом ПАСе написано, что наречия на *впол-* слитно пишутся.

> Я в полроста / вполроста встал.

Comment: В словарь надо смотреть:  в полроста (кусты в полроста)


Русский орфографический словарь  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=вполроста&mode=all  Наречное выражение это.

Comment: Сам вопрос лучше не слешем оформляйте, а так: _(в)полроста_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно на сегодняшний день раздельное написание: ***в полроста***.

Ранее и **ПАС** (см. **[§ 136](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=73#pp73)**), и выпущенный авторами ПАС «Русский орфографический словарь» требовали **слитное** написание этого наречия.
См. фото, сделанное с 4-го издания РОС, вышедшего в 2012 году:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Впоследствии авторами ПАС написание этого наречия было изменено.
См. справочник «**[Орфографическое комментирование русского словаря](https://oross.ruslang.ru/abc/part/ve?start=23090&end=23391)**»:

> **в полро́ста** (кусты́ в полро́ста) [изменено, ср. РОС 2012: **вполроста**]

Такое написание и вошло в последующие переиздания РОС (ПАС пока не переиздавался)…

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а с чем связано такое изменение? Просто ваше мнение: правы ли составители словаря или это "бессмыслица" какая-то? Поэтому "никто не будет так писать", Наш участник категорически не согласен с таким решением.  Если сказать,что лингвисты не могут ошибаться, то это его вряд ли убедит.

Comment: Но остальные наречия с *впол-* я буду только слитно писать!

Answer (score 4):

1. **[ПАС,§ 136](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=73#pp73)**

**Пишутся слитно: 5.** Наречия с первой частью **впол**-, напр.: вполглаза (смотреть), вполголоса, вполнакала, вполноги (играть, кататься, танцевать), вполоборота, вполроста, вполсилы, вполслуха, вполуха (слушать), вполцены; вполоткрыта, вполпьяна, вполсыта.

2. [Русский орфографический словарь](https://%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%20(%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)%20%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C): ***в полроста*** (кусты в полроста).

Это **наречное выражение**, отличается от наречий  падежным управлением, В.п.  Сравнить: ***встать во весь*** рост (В.п.).

3. Интересно, что в Нацкорпусе только два примера с наречием вполроста, но **с другими глаголами:**

**Владимир Войнович.** Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина (1969-1975) Кроме белья, смена байковых зимних портянок, иголка с нитками, огрызок химического карандаша и завернутые в газету шесть фотокарточек, где он **снят был вполроста.**

**Андрей Белый.** Москва. Часть 2. Москва под ударом (1926)
...у села Пересохина (с непросыхающей лужею), где тупоуглые домики криво валились промшелыми крышами, — выбралась у коноплянников; здесь неискосный лопух расширялся **вполроста.**

Вероятно, ***встать в полроста*** нельзя. [Сравнить](https://mel.fm/gramotnost/kak-pisat/3260471-vpoloborota): стоять ***вполоборота***.

4. **Раздельное написание** в 13 примерах, но там наречное выражение относится **к существительному** (является несогласованным определением):

Ирина Ратушинская. Одесситы (1998). *Зина стояла у каменной, **в полроста** ограды.*

С. Е. Каледин. Поп и работник (1991).
*Она повернулась к огромной, **в полроста** иконе в углу за аналоем и заизвинялась перед Богом за недовольство батюшкой, а самое главное, матушкой, Ариадной Евгеньевной.*

Comment: И какой же вывод? Как правильно писать наречие?

Comment: Наречие "вполроста" в современном языке нет, что соответствует словарю. Живем по словарю, это закон. Есть наречное выражение "в полроста", но оно используется в качестве несогласованного определения.  Стоять вполроста нельзя по семантике, вероятная замена: согнувшись, пригнувшись.  Снять вполроста? Тоже придется писать раздельно. Это разговорный вариант: снять на фотографию (какую?) в полроста.

Answer (score 0):

**[Какие словарные рекомендации изменились за последние 8 лет](https://dzen.ru/a/YCDtY_Klbw6qxTmZ)**

**В 2012 году** Российская академия наук выпустила **4-е издание** «Русского орфографического словаря» под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. Эта книга послужила источником для многих статей о грамотности, была ориентиром для корректоров и редакторов. Она же служила базой для проверки слов на «Грамоте» и легла **в основу онлайн-ресурса «АКАДЕМОС».**

Последний — это **официальный электронный словарь РАН,** который постоянно **дополняется**. И после 2012 года **некоторые рекомендации изменились.** Привожу самые интересные из них.

***В пол-лица, в пол-обхвата, в полроста***
Прежние рекомендации: «вполлица», «вполобхвата», **«вполроста»**.

Сейчас правильным считается **раздельное написание.**

**[В полро́ста](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D0%B2+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)**

Comment: Но в самом же справочнике и у Розенталя правило на это есть! Это бессмыслица! https://russkiymir.ru/publications/304465/#:~:text=%D0%9D%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%91%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C,%2C%20%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82 Никто не будет такие наречия раздельно писать!

Comment: https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE/%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0, https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE/%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0

Comment: Максимум *в полроста* так буду писать, но не боле!

Comment: Проверяйте значение  глагола по толковому словарю, если не доверяете орфографическому словарю РАН. Можно "встать во весь рост",  но не вполроста. В карте слов нет "встать вполоборота", а есть "стоять вполоборота".  А это разные глаголы.  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=встать&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts[]=26&dicts[]=42

Comment: Приведите пример предложения с наречием "вполроста",  где вы хотели бы использовать глагол "встать" или любой другой глагол.

Comment: Уходите от диалога или составить не  можете? А вопрос принципиальный.  Может, в нем как раз и кроется причина того, почему  наречие  убрали из словаря.  Или вы больше "не узнаватель нового о русском языке"?   А мы, кстати, тоже уже не совчонки.  Приобретение жизненного опыта))

Comment: Я сказал уже, что это, как исключение, буду в 2 словчонка писать, но остальное — в единую.

Comment: "В полроста"  –  раздельно, то есть в два слова, как наречное сочетание? (Please use the correct terminology.)  А что остальное? В словаре РАН нормировано достаточное количество наречий с формантом ВПОЛ- (слитное написание). А в некоторых случаях возможны два варианта письма:  вполоборота/в пол-оборота.

Comment: Правильность "в полроста" можно обосновать, но вам так и не предложили такого решения. Тогда подумайте сами, вы же хотите узнавать, а не просто слушаться.  Но единственный способ узнавания – это понять почему так, а не иначе.

Comment: Это как *в полметра*.

Comment: Встать в полметра? Так не говорят. Правильно: доска в полметра, кусты в полроста. Это определения. А встать вполоборота можно. Можно еще встать пригнувшись, но точно вполроста не получится)  Вот и делайте вывод.  Рассуждаем дальше:  а что вообще можно сделать вполроста? По литературным источникам вроде бы ничего.